# Save worksheets as workbooks in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

if I have a workbook with 20 or so sheets, is there a way I can easily save each one as their own workbook? Is this possible with scripts?

Comment: Did you do any effort to find the answer by yourself? Did you already tried to write a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a script as follows: (a) get the list of sheets; (b) for each, create a new spreadsheet, naming it after the sheet; (c) copy the sheet there; (d) delete the initial "Sheet1" sheet from the new spreadsheet, so that it doesn't get in the way.

```
function saveEach() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var newss = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheets[i].getSheetName());
    sheets[i].copyTo(newss);
    newss.deleteSheet(newss.getSheets()[0]);
  }
}
```

Reference: [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)